# Print with end=' ', proper formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code**

```
fav_numbers = {
    'bill': [4,6,7,1],
    'uros': [9,0,1,2],
    'pera': [1,6,3,5],
    }

for name, numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print(name.title())
    for num in numbers:
        print(num, end=' ')
```

**Result**

```
Bill
4 6 7 1 Uros
9 0 1 2 Pera
1 6 3 5 [Finished in 0.1s]
```

**Question**
How do I write the for loop so that the last two names are formatted properly?

Comment: `print('\n')` after your nested for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `end=' '`, but the `print(name.title())` that's missing it. Add `end= '` to that, too, to print the numbers into the same line, then finish with a `print()` for the final linebreak.

```
for name, numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print(name.title(), end=' ')  # no newline here
    for num in numbers:
        print(num, end=' ')
    print()                       # but newline here
```

Alternatively, you can use `print` without special parameters and pass the `numbers` as var-arg parameter using `*`.

```
for name, numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print(name.title(), *numbers)
```

This prints the name and the *individual* numbers, all separated with spaces. Both ways, the output is:

```
Pera 1 6 3 5
Bill 4 6 7 1
Uros 9 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add another `print` at the end of the loop to start in a new line:

```
for name, numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print(name.title())
    for num in numbers:
        print(num, end=' ')
    print()
```

Here have it [live](https://repl.it/repls/ShadyFinancialLegacy)

Answer (score 2):

```
fav_numbers = {
    'bill': [4,6,7,1],
    'uros': [9,0,1,2],
    'pera': [1,6,3,5],
    }

for k,v in fav_numbers.items():
    print(k, *v)
```

**Output**

```
bill 4 6 7 1
uros 9 0 1 2
pera 1 6 3 5
```

Comment: Can you please explain the last line?

Comment: i edit this, better to use `*v`, this will unpack the list of numbers

Comment: With the change to `*v`, the description ("list comprehensions") does not fit any more. (Strictly speaking, it was a generator expression before, anyway.)

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0):

`format` is great for printing in a specific format

```
for name,numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name,' '.join((str(n) for n in numbers))))


bill: 4 6 7 1
uros: 9 0 1 2
pera: 1 6 3 5
```

Comment: `join` don't work if in list are int, you need to convert it to str

Answer (score 0):

```
fav_numbers = {
    'bill': [4,6,7,1],
    'uros': [9,0,1,2],
    'pera': [1,6,3,5],
    }

for name,numbers in fav_numbers.items():
    print(", ".join( repr(e) for e in numbers ).replace(',',''),name)
```

**Output**

```
4 6 7 1 bill
9 0 1 2 uros
1 6 3 5 pera
```